# Google Drive Regression: Uploading .docx fails with status 400

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

It looks like a server update made sometime in the last 24 hrs broke .docx file uploads. Is this a known issue? The client code hasn't changed in months and everything worked well until now. Here's a sample trace:

```
2012-10-06 17:55:22 +0000
Request: POST https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder%3A0B2KcmAEFPLoOTDViQlZVYlpQQmc/contents
Request headers:
  Accept: application/atom+xml, text/xml
  Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=_snip_
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Content-Length: 1770
  Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="END_OF_PART"
  GData-Version: 3.0
  Mime-Version: 1.0
  User-Agent: LumenSpark-DailyTracker GData-ObjectiveC/1.12 iPhone_Simulator/6.0 (gzip)

Request body: (1770 bytes)

--END_OF_PART
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8

<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:docs="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007"><category term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#document" scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"/><title>Test</title><published>2012-10-06T10:54:42-07:00</published></entry>
--END_OF_PART
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/msword
<<1241 bytes>>
--END_OF_PART--


Response: status 400
Response headers:
  Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
  Content-Encoding: gzip
  Content-Type: application/vnd.google.gdata.error+xml
  Date: Sat, 06 Oct 2012 17:55:20 GMT
  Expires: Sat, 06 Oct 2012 17:55:20 GMT
  Server: GSE
  Transfer-Encoding: Identity
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Response body: (217 bytes)
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>InvalidEntryException</code><internalReason>We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please try again.</internalReason></error></errors>
```

Comment: Google team - any update on this? It is still happening and customers are complaining...